# Text.PrettyPrint: Starting indentation from left margin

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm trying to generate Javascript using `Text.PrettyPrint`. The problem is that `nest` produces huge indentation when put next to another prettyprinted element. For example, in this code:

```
import Text.PrettyPrint

fun :: Doc
fun = vcat [ text "function" <+> lbrace
           , nest 4 $ vcat $ replicate 5 $ text "// foo"
           , rbrace
           ]

var :: Doc
var = text "var" <+> text "x"

test :: Doc
test = var <+> equals <+> fun <> semi
```

`fun` starts on column 9 in `test` (because of `var <+> equals <> empty` to the left of it), and thus its subsequent lines are indented by 9+4=13 columns:

```
var x = function {
            // foo
            // foo
            // foo
            // foo
            // foo
        };
```

Is there a way to render indentations from the left margin, so that the above would be rendered instead as

```
var x = function {
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
};
```

?

Comment: Daan Leijen's pretty printer `wl-pprint` has more flexible handling for indenting than the Hughes Peyton-Jones pretty printer. You might want to consider using it instead. See the manual for documentation, it is much more detailed than the Haddock docs.

Comment: I think `wl-pprint` will turn out to be the right solution -- I am ready to accept this as an answer if you post it as such.

Comment: @Cactus did you ever get this working with `wl-pprint`? If so, why don't you add an answer for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is indeed to use [`wl-pprint`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint) (and replace `nest` with `indent`). Then, the code given yields

```
var x = function {
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
    // foo
};
```

as desired. For anyone still intent on working something with trying to hack on `pretty`, note that although the constructors for `Doc` aren't exposed, you can still get at them via `Generic` with `-XPatternSynonyms`:

```
-- | Means of exposing the data constructors of `Doc` from `pretty`
pattern GEmpty              = M1 (L1 (L1 (L1 (M1 U1))))
pattern GNilAbove doc       = M1 (L1 (L1 (R1 (M1 (M1 (K1 doc))))))
pattern GTextBeside d doc   = M1 (L1 (R1 (L1 (M1 (M1 (K1 d) :*: M1 (K1 doc))))))
pattern GNest n doc         = M1 (L1 (R1 (R1 (M1 (M1 (K1 n) :*: M1 (K1 doc))))))
pattern GUnion ldoc rdoc    = M1 (R1 (L1 (L1 (M1 (M1 (K1 ldoc) :*: M1 (K1 rdoc))))))
pattern GNoDoc              = M1 (R1 (L1 (R1 (M1 U1))))
pattern GBeside ldoc s rdoc = M1 (R1 (R1 (L1 (M1 (M1 (K1 ldoc) :*: M1 (K1 s) :*: M1 (K1 rdoc))))))
pattern GAbove ldoc b rdoc  = M1 (R1 (R1 (R1 (M1 (M1 (K1 ldoc) :*: M1 (K1 b) :*: M1 (K1 rdoc))))))
```

The problem is mostly not violating any of the many invariants the library has under the hood.

---

As a side note, I also found [`wl-pprint-annotated`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/wl-pprint-annotated-0.0.1.3), a modern re-write of `wl-pprint`, with which one has access to underlying data constructors (at the cost of needing to keep in mind the invariants involved). This is actually the package I will end up using.

In particular, it lets me make this sort of brace block such that if it is small enough it will go on only one line:

```
-- | Asserts a 'Doc a' cannot render on multiple lines.
oneLine :: Doc a -> Bool
oneLine (WL.FlatAlt d _) = oneLine d
oneLine (WL.Cat a b) = oneLine a && oneLine b
oneLine (WL.Union a b) = oneLine a && oneLine b
oneLine (WL.Annotate _ d) = oneLine d
oneLine WL.Line = False
oneLine _ = True

-- | Make a curly-brace delimited block. When possible, permit fitting everything on one line
block :: Doc a -> Doc a
block b | oneLine b = hsep ["{", b, "}"] `WL.Union` vsep [ "{", indent 2 b, "}" ]
        | otherwise = vsep [ "{", indent 2 b, "}" ]
```

Then I get nice results that automatically do or don't span multiple lines:

```
ghci> "function" <> parens "x" <+> block ("return" <+> "x" <> semi)
function(x) { return x; }
ghci> "function" <> parens "x" <+> block ("x" <> "++" <> semi <#> "return" <+> "x" <> semi)
function(x) {
  x++;
  return x;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
offset = 1 + length (render $ var <+> equals)
hang empty (negate offset) test
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work; in fact, it looks just like without that extra `hang`. Plus, wouldn't it have a terrible performance impact?

Comment: No it's not the lack of `<+>`, I figured that part out myself. But I get the same output.

Comment: Works for me. pretty-1.1.1.0.

Comment: This might work in some cases, but it will break in more nested cases (rendering a `Doc` can give different results depending on whether the `Doc` is part of something bigger). And the performance hit for nested cases would also be pretty hefty.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the desired result by applying `vcat` to a list where the first item includes also the variable definition and assignment.

Example:

```
fun :: Doc
fun = vcat [ var <+> equals <+> text "function" <+> lbrace
           , nest 4 $ vcat $ replicate 5 $ text "// foo"
           , rbrace
           ]

var :: Doc
var = text "var" <+> text "x"

test :: Doc
test = fun <> semi
```

Comment: Of course I can do this - the problem is that I want the whole `function { ... }` to still be one `Doc` (not a list of lines). This way, `pretty` can still choose a nice layout for me (i.e. whether `function { .. }` even needs to span multiple lines).

Comment: Right, but I couldn't find another (more elegant) way of doing it. The main issue here is that you're putting the `var` `Doc` _beside_ the `fun` `Doc`, this will set `fun`'s indentation offset according to the length of the doc that has been concatenated to. On the contrary concatenating two docs _above_ one another will keep the indentation offset unaltered within the doc unless one of the two docs is a `Nest`.